# Rails admin unwanted add button in edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, rails-admin

In my config actions (rails_admin initializer) i have this config:

```
...  
config.actions do  
...  
  new do  
    only [X, Y]  
   end  
...  
end
```

and when editing my model **Z** i have an unwanted button **Save an add another**.
How to avoid that?

Thank you

Comment: do you want to except some actions ?

Comment: i already except my model Z in the show block